# Apache Guacamole Home Directory Issue

Tags: apache, tomcat7, guacamole

As part of the Apache Guacamole setup you create a GUACAMOLE_HOME directory for the extension/configuration files etc

I used `/etc/guacamole`

Then I exported it `export GUACAMOLE_HOME=/etc/guacamole`

And `chmod 0777 /etc/guacamole -R`

the `printenv` command shows the variable `GUACAMOLE_HOME=/etc/guacamole`

But, when I start the Tomcat7 service, it ignores my guacamole.properties file which is in the GUACAMOLE_HOME:

```
16:33:56.389 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
o.a.g.environment.LocalEnvironment - No guacamole.properties file
found within GUACAMOLE_HOME or the classpath. Using defaults.

16:33:57.013 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
o.a.g.environment.LocalEnvironment - No guacamole.properties file
found within GUACAMOLE_HOME or the classpath. Using defaults.
```

The service seems to start, but Guacamole is running with defaults...

What is the missing step here??

Comment: use the answer from this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499048/the-user-mapping-xml-file-doesnt-work-in-guacamole-invalid-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499048/the-user-mapping-xml-file-doesnt-work-in-guacamole-invalid-login)

Answer (score 2):

Guacamole is running under tomcat, and the tomcat server is probably starting under tomcat user. It might be the case that you have defined GUACAMOLE_HOME in your shell, but this is not visible by tomcat user.

I prefer to store guacamole.properties file under .guacamole directory, the 3rd option in the manual:

> 3. The directory .guacamole, located within the home directory of the user running the servlet container.

On ubuntu-like systems, default tomcat installation is started under tomcat7 or tomcat8 user, depending on the version. You may do the following:

```
cd ~tomcat7
sudo ln -s /etc/guacamole .guacamole
```

This will make a .guacamole link to your configuration directory, in the home directory of the user running the servlet container, as described in the manual.