# Guacamole ,Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: tomcat7, guacamole

I'm facing same problem as   ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499048/the-user-mapping-xml-file-doesnt-work-in-guacamole-invalid-login#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499048/the-user-mapping-xml-file-doesnt-work-in-guacamole-invalid-login#)

However, it doesn't solve my problem so far.

Mine is `guacamole-client-1.0.0` on tomcat 7.0.76 and CentOS 7.8.2003.

I did `ln -s /etc/guacamole/ /usr/share/tomcat/.guacamole` and `restart tomcat`

Then,google Chrome shows.

```
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://10.0.3.13:8080/guacamole-1.0.0/api/tokens`
```

I need farther information to fix the problem.

This is a message in log.

```
10.0.20.111 - - [23/Jun/2020:21:15:44 +0900] "GET /guacamole-1.0.0/api/tokens HTTP/1.1" 500 183
```

Comment: I found  `<connection name="localhost">` was  `<connection name="localhost'>` in `user-mapping.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented,I made misspelling in  `user-mapping.xml`.

After I fix the error,guacamole goes forward.

Comment: I've also seen this when using other authentication methods (i.e.: LDAP) where the AD binder account is not able to connect to the LDAP server or perhaps if the MySQL PW is wrong or unreachable).  Check the Tomcat logs.  You can also enable debug for more info.