# Guacamole disconnect RDP silently

Tags: windows, rdp, guacamole

I use guacamole-client-1.0.0 on tomcat 7.0.76 and CentOS 7.8.2003

I solved this issue [403 (Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534853/guacamole-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-403-f)

However,I can't connect RDP yet with the message ONLY `Error connecting to RDP server` in tomcat's log.

Here is `user-mapping.xml`

```
<authorize username="test" password="test#123">
   <connection name="10.0.3.111">
           <protocol>rdp</protocol>
           <param name="hostname">10.0.3.111</param>
           <param name="port">3389</param>
           <param name="username">*****</param> 
           <param name="password">*****</param>
           <param name="domain">****</param>                                                                                              
    </connection>
  </authorize>
```

I've checked packets by fireshark.

Both Gugacamole host and target desktop PC are exchanging some packets based on 3389.

However,I can't find any error packet from result of wireshaek.

Packets in Guacamole host

```
# tshark -i ens192 -f 'tcp port 3389' 
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'ens192'
  1 0.000000000    10.0.3.13 -> 10.0.3.111   TCP 74 34644 > ms-wbt-server [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=99213719 TSecr=0 WS=128
  2 0.000153298   10.0.3.111 -> 10.0.3.13    TCP 66 ms-wbt-server > 34644 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64000 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1
  3 0.000168688    10.0.3.13 -> 10.0.3.111   TCP 54 34644 > ms-wbt-server [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0
  4 0.000550557    10.0.3.13 -> 10.0.3.111   COTP 92 CR TPDU src-ref: 0x0000 dst-ref: 0x0000
  5 0.004661563   10.0.3.111 -> 10.0.3.13    TCP 60 ms-wbt-server > 34644 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=39 Win=0 Len=0
```

Packets in target Desktop PC

```
149 6.261424    10.0.3.13   10.0.3.111  TCP 74  34644  >  3389 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=99213719 TSecr=0 WS=128
150 6.261506    10.0.3.111  10.0.3.13   TCP 66  3389  >  34644 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64000 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1
151 6.26157 10.0.3.13   10.0.3.111  TCP 60  34644  >  3389 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0
152 6.261955    10.0.3.13   10.0.3.111  SSL 92  Continuation Data
153 6.266009    10.0.3.111  10.0.3.13   TCP 54  3389  >  34644 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=39 Win=0 Len=0
```

How I can find more detailed information.

Comment: I've found I should change the value of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp>SecurityLayer '  fron 2 to 1.

Comment: It works fine.But i don't know how related to the problem.Give me someone's idea as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Guacamole doc](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#rdp), you can configure the "security" property.

With you comment, I understand that you need this in your user-maping.xml:

```
<authorize username="test" password="test#123">
   <connection name="10.0.3.111">
           <protocol>rdp</protocol>
           <param name="hostname">10.0.3.111</param>
           <param name="port">3389</param>
           <param name="username">*****</param> 
           <param name="password">*****</param>
           <param name="domain">****</param>
           <param name="security">2</param>
    </connection>
</authorize>
```

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't match for me.I still need to set Registry value.